# Calculate the length of a full meridian of the sphere$S^2$ using the 1st form fundamental.

Tags: differential-geometry

I was studying the Do Carmo book, but I couldn't exactly understand the definition of the 1st form fundamental. How can i resolve it using the 1FF?

1FF: the first form fundamental will be the cuadratic form $I_{p}(w)=<w,w>_{p}=|w|^2>0$ for a regular surface $S R^3$ in $p \in S$

Then, I know that $S^2 = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3; x^2 + y^2 +  z^2 = 1 \}$

My question is, what is exactly a full meridian?
it is not the full circle? then i can just take the circle $\alpha(t) = (cos(t),sen(t))$
i believe i can just take the derivate and calculate
Then the answer would be 2$\pi$?

Comment: What is your book's exact definition of the first fundamental form?

Comment: It is something you have to set up yourself.  Do not ask us to do it for you.  What coordinates would be good to use to describe a "full meridian" of the sphere?  What is the first fundamental form in those coordinates?  What integral do you need to use to compute arc length?